# 'su user' behavior differs when logged in locally vs via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, users, password, su

On my Ubuntu 18.04 system, there's a user called `myuser` without a password:

```
tester@box:~$ passwd -S myuser
myuser NP 03/31/2020 0 99999 7 -1
```

When I log in to the machine locally and switch to `myuser` via `su myuser` everything works as expected, no password prompt, I'm directly switched to the specified user.

However, when I log in to the same machine via SSH, and then run `su myuser`, I get prompted for a password.

Edit: Same user used for logging in locally and via SSH.

Where does this difference in behavior come from? There must be a explanation, currently I'm a bit lost.

Comment: What user do you log on as when you log on locally? Is it the same user as when you ssh?

Comment: Yes, same user -> but different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `nullok_secure` with `nullok` in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`. You may also need to adjust values in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` if you have some specific overrides.
You should have something like this in your common-auth file:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Do you have some additional explanation or recommended reading for me to understand what exactly is going?

Comment: For those lookink for an explanation, see 'options' in the [pam_unix man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_unix.8.html).
With ssh I end up with a pseudo tty (`pts/0` to be exact), whereas I get `tty1` with a local login. (Check e.g. with `who am i`).
`tty1` is listed in `/etc/securetty` while `pts/0` is not. The default `nullok_secure` value in the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` config will check that file and block if the tty isn't listed, which here was the case with ssh.